# Auto resize height of element

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I want to create a banner like this http://www.firstborn.com/

I have got 3 different images loading in at different resolutions but the part i am struggling with it finding JQuery to replicate the sizing.

This banners height reduces with the screen size so if you just drag your browser viewport smaller you will see what i mean.

i want to set the height initially for 3 or 4 set sizes then have the height reduce or enlarge depending on the screen.

Ideally the solution needs to be as widely supported as possible :)

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set following css properties to your element:

```
position:absolute;
height:auto;
```

That's it. Let me know if you are still then facing any problem..!!!